# Can't find a Python module in AppleScript

Tags: python, applescript, todoist

I created a Python script that uses the Todoist API to export my task list to a list of strings (I want to paste them as Discord messages) and it works fine if I run the command on the Terminal window, but if I run the same command using AppleScript, an error is thrown, saying `No module named todoist.api`.
Here's the code: (I have only one line)

```
do shell script "$HOME/tasks.sh"
```

The shell scripts runs the python scripts I need, but the problem is in the imports of those files, which are:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from todoist.api import TodoistAPI
import pyperclip
import os
import MyTodoist
```

in the first file (`tasks.py`) and

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from todoist.api import TodoistAPI
import pyperclip
import os
```

in the second file (`MyTodoist.py`)
The final goal is to store the result of a function in `tasks.py` in a variable in my script, but I don't know how. Can someone help me please?

Comment: `do shell script` does not automatically read your bash/zsh profile, so you may need to define Python-related environment variables yourself.

Comment: @foo okay, how do I do it? I'm still new to AppleScript...

Comment: That’s really a shell/Python question. IIRC `do shell script` runs [ba]sh itself, so you’d define a new environment variable using `export NAME=VALUE`, e.g. `export PYTHONPATH=/some/path:/another/path; rest-of-your-commands`. Depends on how your shell, Python,etc are configured on your own machine. Running `env` in Terminal will list all the environment variables defined there, which may help you work out which ones to include. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) may also be helpful.

Comment: @foo thank you! The link seems really helpful, I'll check it out right away!